# Magento2 set all product infos to "use default value"

Tags: magento2, importexport

I have a problem with imported products in Magento 2 shop. Import worked well, but all products have own product name, product description, short description and so on for Store View AND Default Store View. This is not good, because we only have 1 language and my client has to change content twice.

How can I set to all info of products that default value of "Store View" should be used? Is there a database command I can run or export/import products via CSV ...?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To achieve this, you have to change attribute scope to global when import the product using CSV.
>
> Please refer below image for changing the scope of the attribute

[image]